# Using template inheritance with Assemble

Tags: handlebars.js, template-engine, gruntjs, assemble

Is is possible to define regions in the template, that would pull content from the page?

Let's say I have in my template the following structure:

```
<div class=sidebar></div>
<div class=content></div>
```

And from the page content, I would like to pull some html content to the sidebar, and other content to content div.

Is this possible?

Comment: Where does this template come from? And with what language are you going to pull the content from the page? Javascript?

Comment: @NoLifeKing my project has the following structure:

`templates/layouts/default.hbs`

and the pages:
`templates/pages/*.hbs`

The general idea would be to enforce html structure on my content, but have that structure defined at template level, so that I don't need to repeat that structure in every page.

Comment: @LuisMartins, did I answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

**With Swig as the Engine**

Yes, this is possible. Seehttps://github.com/assemble/boilerplate-swig, in particular, [this example](https://github.com/assemble/boilerplate-swig/blob/master/src/filters.swig#L26-L31), which shows how to use `{% macro %}` tags to accomplish what you're asking about.

If you want to use Swig, be sure to look at the readme as the [assemble-swig](https://github.com/assemble/assemble-swig) repo as well. You have to register swig as the current engine in assemble:

```
assemble: {
  options: {
    engine: 'swig'
  }
}
```

**With Handlebars as the Engine**

If the sidebar content will always be the same, on every page then you can use partials for this. Even if the URLs or active classes change on each page, this should work.

However, dynamic content using template or "block" inheritance, e.g. `extend` can be achieved with [Handlebars helpers](http://assemble.io/docs/helpers/helpers-content.html).

But since [layouts](http://assemble.io/docs/options-layout.html) are used with [assemble](http://assemble.io) this is a bit trickier to do with "out-of-the-box" helpers. To clarify, just about any helper I can think of will work great with assemble out-of-the-box, except for this - specifically because of how layouts work.

My suggestion is that you add to the existing feature request(s) for this on assemble and/or the handlebars-helpers project to add your use case and thoughts on what you want to achieve:

- https://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/38
- https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers/issues/16

Answer (score 1):

@jonschlinkert You should update assemble's documentation, cause start with Assemble isn't so easy and a lot of things are little hidden.

So Luis, you can try this method, which currently works great for me too!

[Assemble: Multiple points of content insertion in layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800813/assemble-multiple-points-of-content-insertion-in-layout/19826339#19826339)